# Debian Wheezy dual monitor problem

Tags: linux, debian, xorg, drivers

I installed Debian wheezy with XFCE 4.8 on my new laptop, updated the kernel to 3.13 from backports.

When I connect the laptop to my monitor, I can see only a part of the screen on the monitor with a very low resolution. On my old laptop, I used to fix that using XFCE display settings or ARandR but now both don't detect the new monitor even though its obviously working.

I didn't install any proprietary drivers. I don't have xorg.conf. Here is the output of xrandr:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080       0.0*
```

Here is the (hopefully) relevant output of lspci:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1292 (rev a1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest installing Nvidia Graphics Drivers:

1. Add "contrib" and "non-free" components to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

   ```
   deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
   ```
2. Update the list of available packages and install the appropriate linux-headers and kernel module packages:

   ```
   $ aptitude update
   $ aptitude -r install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') nvidia-kernel-dkms
   ```

More info: https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers

Comment: I tried `nvidia-detect` first as the wiki suggests but it says: No NVIDIA GPU detected.